# In turtlebot2, the connection is very difficult

Tags: ros, turtlebot2, turtlebot, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm beginner of ROS. So, I want to practice the ROS through the Turtlebot! But, it is very difficult!

I'm proceding the "TurtleBot Bringup" session. The first, I typed "roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch" in remote PC followiwng the manual. But it occured, "ERROR : unable to contact ROS master at [http:// my_IP] The traceback for the exception was written to the log file".

What should I do?

Actually, I cannot assure that I did well the precedent procedure! Help me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271729/in-turtlebot2,-the-connection-is-very-difficult/) by [suwonlee](https://answers.ros.org/users/32054/suwonlee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-28**:
Please update your question with the results of

```
echo $ROS_MASTER_URI
```

,

```
echo $ROS_IP
```

and

```
echo $ROS_HOSTNAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a beginner too :), I think you have to run this command on your turtlebot computer by remoting in (telenet, ssh etc) and not your remote computer.
Also make sure you can ping the turtlebot IP and have set the environmental variables.

Tushar.

---

Originally posted by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) with karma: 68 on 2017-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2021-09-04**:
What's the actual procedure for controlling the robot with the remote PC, I'm having issues too. So you are saying I have to run the bringup on the turtlebot computer first? then I use the remote PC to connect(ssh) the turtlebot computer, then I can control the robot and run launch files from the remote PC?